# How do you check if JSON data is an object, or a String?

Tags: android, json, string, object

I'm currently working on an app that pulls a JSON string from a API. The problem is, a space can change how the data is pulled.

For example:

With a space, the JSON comes through as an object i need to parse to get the content;

```
    "d:Street1": {
      "-xml:space": "preserve",
      "#text": "123 space street "
    },
```

Without a space, it's simply pulling the string;

```
"d:Street1": "123 space street",
```

How do i check if "d:Street1" is a JSONObject, or just a string?

EDIT: Solution

```
Object street1 = jobProperties.get("d:Street1");

            if (street1 instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject JobStreet11 = jobProperties.getJSONObject("d:Street1");
                jobStreet1 = JobStreet11.getString("content");
            } else {
                jobStreet1 = jobProperties.getString("d:Street1");
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a space can change how the data is pulled" ?

Comment: If you look above, the only difference in the Street name put into the system is a space at the end. They don't trim anything, so it saves the space too which comes out as option 1. Without a space at the end of Street 1 it comes out as option 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this conditions

```
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();

if (json instanceof JSONObject){

}else if (json instanceof JSONArray){

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll change it a bit, but i think this could work :) Will give it a try and come back to mark as correct if so.

Comment: I changed this a little but it works thank you :) Refer to EDIT above.

Comment: Happy that you done :)
Put your final code if you can

Comment: Final code can be seen in the EDIT above :) Thanks again.